# How to create a commutation matrix in C++ (using either Eigen or Armadillo?)

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, armadillo

I am wondering how to create a commutation matrix (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix#MATLAB) in C++ using either the Eigen or Armadillo libraries. There is some MATLAB code on the wiki page:

```
function P = com_mat(m, n)

% determine permutation applied by K
A = reshape(1:m*n, m, n);
v = reshape(A', 1, []);

% apply this permutation to the rows (i.e. to each column) of identity matrix
P = eye(m*n);
P = P(v,:);
```

I am wondering if anybody has a function in C++ to do this or could convert this to C++ code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can pretty much convert it step-by-step to Eigen code starting with Eigen-3.4, which introduced the [`reshaped`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshape.html) method.

```cpp
  Eigen::MatrixXf A(3, 2);
  A <<
    1.f, 4.f,
    2.f, 5.f,
    3.f, 6.f;
  std::cout << A << "\n\n";
  /*
   * output:
   * 1 4
   * 2 5
   * 3 6
   */
  using PermutationMatrixXi =
    Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, int>;
  PermutationMatrixXi p(A.size());
  p.indices() = Eigen::VectorXi::LinSpaced(A.size(), 0, A.size() - 1)
        .reshaped(A.cols(), A.rows()).transpose().reshaped(A.size(), 1);
  std::cout << p.indices().transpose() << "\n\n";
  /*
   * output: 0 2 4 1 3 5
   */
  Eigen::VectorXf pa = p * A.reshaped(A.size(), 1);
  std::cout << pa.transpose() << "\n\n";
  /*
   * output: 1 4 2 5 3 6
   */
  Eigen::MatrixXi P = p.toDenseMatrix();
  std::cout << P << "\n\n";
  /*
   * output:
   * 1 0 0 0 0 0
   * 0 0 0 1 0 0
   * 0 1 0 0 0 0
   * 0 0 0 0 1 0
   * 0 0 1 0 0 0
   * 0 0 0 0 0 1
   */
  Eigen::VectorXf pa = p * A.reshaped(A.size(), 1);
  std::cout << pa.transpose() << "\n\n";
  /*
   * output: 1 4 2 5 3 6
   */
```

Note that `reshaped` is a rather slow operation since its index operations involve integer divisions and modulos. If you require speed, you might want to build the permutation manually, which isn't too hard, and use `Eigen::Map` to reshape the matrix.

```cpp
  Eigen::MatrixXf A(3, 2);
  [...]
  PermutationMatrixXi p(A.size());
  Eigen::VectorXi& pi = p.indices();
  for(int col = 0, cols = A.cols(); col < cols; ++col)
    for(int row = 0, rows = A.rows(); row < rows; ++row)
      pi[col * rows + row] = row * cols + col;
  assert(A.innerStride() == 1 && A.outerStride() == A.rows());
  Eigen::VectorXf pa = p * Eigen::VectorXf::Map(A.data(), A.size());
```

Note the assertion: The `Map` only works for dense matrices or column-blocks; not arbitrary blocks of larger matrices. Evaluate into a new dense matrix if required.